# Check if at least one row is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 rows with 3 inputs in each. What I need is to check if at least in one row all inputs are filled. If one row is filled then we go to other page. There is no difference between which row is filled, it could be even last row.
Here's my piece of code:

```
             <div class="div-rows row-1">
                <input name="kfz_first_name" type="text" placeholder="Vorname" data-input="1"/>
                <input name="kfz_last_name" type="text" placeholder="Nachname" data-input="1"/>
                <input name="kfz_birthday" class="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="Geburtsdatum" data-input="1"/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-rows row-2">
                <input name="kfz_first_name" type="text" placeholder="Vorname" data-input="2"/>
                <input name="kfz_last_name" type="text" placeholder="Nachname" data-input="2"/>
                <input name="kfz_birthday" class="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="Geburtsdatum" data-input="2"/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-rows row-3">
                <input name="kfz_first_name" type="text" placeholder="Vorname" data-input="3"/>
                <input name="kfz_last_name" type="text" placeholder="Nachname" data-input="3"/>
                <input name="kfz_birthday" class="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="Geburtsdatum" data-input="3"/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <a href="#" class="x-btn">click</a>

        var zaza = true;
        $('.div-rows input').each(function(){
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
                $(this).addClass('red-border');
                zaza = false;
            }
            if (zaza == false) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please mention what is not working

Comment: I actually get to the other step, whyle my fields are not filled. I need to go to next stepa after one row is completelly filled.

Answer (score 1):

You have a scope issue. `return false` breaks the `$.each` part. Check for false after iterating.

```
var zaza = true;
$('.div-rows input').each(function(){
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
        $(this).addClass('red-border');
        zaza = false;
    }
});
if (zaza == false) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your correction, it helped.
But still not what I've wanted. Now it checks if all fields are filled. And I need to check if all 3 fields in one row are filled.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, not tested, but you'll get the idea.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(document).on('click', '.x-btn', function() { 
    var canContinue= true;

    $('.div-rows').each(function() { 
      var allInRowsAreEmpty = true;

      $('input', $(this)).each(function() { 
        if($(this).val() != '') { // $(this) = the current input in the current .div-rows
          allInRowAreEmpty = false;
        }
      });

      if(allEmpty) {
        $(this).addClass('your-error-class'); // $(this) is the current .div-rows
        canContinue= false;
      }
    });

    if(canContinue) {
      // do your thing
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: that is just checking if one input is filled in... not a row

Comment: Your logic is still not making sure one whole row is filled in.